# can't change colour of background swing

Tags: java, spring, colors, background

I can't change the colour of my background in swing. It is a really simple pong game I was just messing around with but I can't change the background colour. Here is my code [the background colour is changed in the main](I know it's messy, I'm still learning):

```
public class Pong extends JPanel {
     int x = 0;
     int y = 000;
     int yP = 300;
     int xP = 300;

     int border = 50;
     boolean ballGoingDown = true;
     boolean ballGoingRight = true;

     private void moveBall() throws InterruptedException {
         if (ballGoingRight == true) {
             x++;
         }

         if (ballGoingRight == false) {
             x--;
         }


         if (ballGoingDown == true) {
             y++;
         }

         if (ballGoingDown == false) {
             y--;
         }

         if (y == getHeight() - border) {
             ballGoingDown = false;
         }

         if (y == 0) {
             ballGoingDown = true;
         }

         if (x == getWidth() - border) {
             ballGoingRight = false;
         }

         if (x == 0) {
             ballGoingRight = true;
         }
     }


     @
     Override
     public void paint(Graphics G) {
         super.paint(G);
         G.fillOval(x, y, 50, 50);
     }

     public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
         JFrame frame = new JFrame("Pong");
         frame.setSize(700, 500);

         frame.setVisible(true);
         frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.red);
         frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
         frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         Pong game = new Pong();
         frame.add(game);

         while (true) {
             game.repaint();
             game.moveBall();
             Thread.sleep(1);

         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Since your `Pong` class is a `JPanel` you should change the background of `game` object. Try `game.setBackground(Color.red);` instead of `frame.getContentPane().setBackground(..)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the *JFrame's* background to be red, but you've added a JPanel which covers it.

You can fix this by changing:

```
frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.red);
```

to

```
game.setBackground(Color.red);
```

Comment: That doesn't work, it just underlines game and says it 'cannot find symbol'. am i inserting that line in the right place?

Comment: Thats because you need to put the line UNDER `Pong game = new Pong();`!!!

Comment: You need to do it between `Pong game = new Pong();` and `frame.add(game);`. Then it will work.